# AJAX 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have some issue with a web application instance that I migrated recently to the new server. The weird thing is that the instance works locally but when on the server it shows the following on console log:

```
POST http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?module=MailManager&view=Index&_operation=folder&_operationarg=open&_folder=INBOX&_page=0 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send 
f.extend.ajax 
f.(anonymous function) 
MailManager.folder_open 
MailManager.openCurrentFolder
MailManager.mainui
(anonymous function)
n
o.fireWith
e.extend.ready
c.addEventListener.C


POST http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php?module=MailManager&view=Index&_operation=mainui 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
send
f.extend.ajax
f.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
```

Any help would really be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to any error logs on the server that may help identify the issue?

Comment: look at the server's error log. it'll have more details about the 500

Comment: That's a server a error. Nothing to be done on client side. Check server codes or logs.

Comment: No access to the server log but does anyone have any idea what it could be? I am using php version 5.3.10

Comment: Why don't you use a rest client like postman to send the same petition   to your server, that way at least you will get more information that the console log. (At least that's what i do when i have some trouble with yii and php )

Comment: first check the server's error log then check the htaccess file in our server or rename it. also make sure that Documentroot in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file if your server is linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I installed the php imap extension and that fixed the problem.

Thanks anyway for your answers!